# Does chef-client run on startup?

Tags: linux, mongodb, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

Does chef-client run as part of a server's startup or just on the next internal set by the chef-client cookbook?

Is there a chef-client cookbook setting to make servers do a chef-client run as soon as they bootup (didn't see one) without having to manually edit startup scripts?

I am asking because I am disabling transparent pages (as per [this mongo doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/transparent-huge-pages/)).

I can easily have a recipe echo the right parameter to the correct files, but on reboot the setting switches back. If I know chef-client will run on reboot first thing I won't have to worry about messing with startup scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, chef-client is not configured to be run as init task. Though, The chef-client can be run as a daemon. chef-client cookbook can be used to configure the chef-client as a daemon. Add the default recipe to a node’s run-list, and then use attributes in that cookbook to configure the behavior of the chef-client.

https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html#run-as-a-service

If you want you can configure it as init service with chef-client::init_service recipe.

https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/chef-client/blob/master/recipes/init_service.rb

Comment: OK just making sure, so if I add that recipe to the nodes run list it will kick off a chef-client run when it boots?

Comment: First, you have to configure chef-client as service by executing that recipe on that node. Next time, when it boots/re-boots, chef-client will kick off.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can run chef using cron, there is special 'macro' @reboot, you should add similar line to your crontab:

   ```
   @reboot /path/to/my/chef-client
   ```
2. Some Linux distributions support `/etc/rc.local` file (Debian/Ubuntu for sure) or similar file which is executed.